# Ruby Text/Sentiment Analysis

Tags: ruby, text-analysis

I have two strings -

`"I like running around the track.`

`I like swimming in the pool, but only in the morning.`

I need to pull out what people "like" from the above two comments (`running around the track` and `swimming in the pool`.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a text analytics gem or other method of pulling in that kind of information? I don't necessarily need word counts or n-grams, I just want to know what words are seen in relation to the word "`like`".

Comment: How would you parse, `I don't like swimming` or `It's like, blue`

Comment: I have seen other gems that make it relatively easy to take the word "`swimming`" and "`blue`" and determine if they are nouns or verbs. I can take the results and pass them through a loop, saving only verbs. This isn't an ideal or wholesome fix, but for this specific project I think something like that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick-and-dirty fix, you could use a Regex to search for all the forms of "like" and pull out all the text between there and the punctuation mark or Newline character.

Comment: This was my original idea, I was just hoping there was something like this already out there that was relatively simple to use. I'll go with this method and just do some analysis on the output to ensure it is what I need. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good call.  In general, you probably don't want to bother with tools that are more complex than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dependency parser such as [The Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)
to parse your text and find the keys words in your sentiment dictionary, and probably put some constraints on the type of dependencies for disambiguation. For example, the dependency needs to be of type "dobj" (direct object). Then follow the dependency structures to the end of phrase or sentence depending on your needs.